# JDA get emotes APIs always return null or empty lists

Tags: discord, discord-jda

I have tried every method I can find to retrieve emotes by their IDs. The football emote ID is 881204535253676072. None of these work.

```
JDA jda = JDABuilder.createDefault(token)
            .enableCache(CacheFlag.EMOTE)
            .build();
jda.awaitReady();

// Always returns null
Emote football = jda.getEmoteById(881204535253676072L);

Guild guild = jda.getGuildById(MyGuildId);
// Always returns null
Emote football = guild.getEmoteById(881204535253676072L);

SnowflakeCacheView<Emote> emotes = jda.getEmoteCache();
// Always returns null
Emote football = emotes.getElementById(881204535253676072L);

// Always returns empty lists
List<Emote> emotes = jda.getEmotesByName(":football:", true);
List<Emote> emotes = jda.getEmotesByName("football", true);
List<Emote> emotes = jda.getEmotesByName("881204535253676072", true);
List<Emote> emotes = guild.getEmotesByName(":football:", true);
List<Emote> emotes = guild.getEmotesByName("football", true);
List<Emote> emotes = guild.getEmotesByName("881204535253676072", true);
```

The bot has administrator privileges in the guild. The JDA documentation is non-existent for this operation. I'm just about convinced that these APIs don't work and may never have worked, but I thought I would ask here first. Any ideas?

Comment: How did you get those ids?

Comment: That is not a valid emote id. You can see that this asset link gives a 404 which means the ID is not for an emote, you likely copied the message id instead. https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/881204535253676072.png

Comment: Looks like that is true. Dumb mistake. So, how do you get the IDs of existing Discord emotes?

Comment: If you mean the football *emoji*, then they don't have any id and cannot be represented by an Emote instance in JDA. If you mean custom emotes that are uploaded to servers, you can get it by copying the link and getting it there.